# Stored Proc returns 2 return values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored proc that first checks if an entry exists and if so updates it then returns the row ID, if not it inserts a new record then returns the row ID.

When executing the stored proc I am given 2 return values, one with the field '@PersonID' and the other with 'Return Value'. I'm pretty sure this is happening because of the SELECT statement that is used in the IF EXISTS, however, I'm unable to figure a way to suppress it and I was hoping someone could help.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertPerson] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @FirstName nvarchar(50),
    @LastName nvarchar(50),
    @PersonID int OUT
AS
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF( EXISTS (SELECT PersonID FROM People 
                WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName))
    BEGIN

        SET @PersonID = (SELECT PersonID
                 FROM People
                 WHERE FirstName = @FirstName
                       AND LastName = @LastName)

        UPDATE People
        SET
        FirstName = @FirstName,
        LastName = @LastName
        WHERE PersonID = @PersonID
    END
    ELSE

    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO People (FirstName, LastName) VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName)
    SET @PersonID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    SELECT @PersonID
END
```

Comment: You declared an out parameter as well as selecting the value - surely you only need one or the other...

Comment: remove `SELECT @PersonID` .. the procedure has an out parameter @PersonID and you are already setting it.

Comment: Every stored procedure will ALWAYS return a value in Return_Value as an int. It is intended to indicate a status of the execution.

Comment: You should not use the Return_Value to carry meaningful data. It is for stored procedure execution status (Success, failure, error codes to distinguish among error modes, etc.) use a Select statement to carry data.  You can return an out parameter, (as you at doing), or a single column single row resultset, (as `Select @PersonId` is doing, and modify your client code to read the value from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the quick responses. I had accidently posted some incorrect code, the actual stored proc doesn't have SELECT @PersonID at the end. However, I think I have incorrectly identified the stored proc as the root cause of the issue I'm working on and as pointed out in the responses everything is working as expected.

Thanks again for the help